# Why is Autofac injecting null into my constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am having issues with my DI in a C# project. When I run my test I am getting an error that says Object reference is not set to an instant of an Object.  It is failing on the `var retryPolicy = _retryPolicyHelper.GetRetryPolicy<>();` call and I'm not sure why. I thought the DI with the constructor handles the instantiation of the object.

```
internal read only IRetryPolicyHelper _retryPolicyHelper;
internal read only ILogger _logger;
public Constructor(IRetryPolicyHelper retryPolicyHelper, ILogger logger;)
{
 _retryPolicyHelper = retryPolicyHelper;
 _logger = logger;
}

public async Task SomeName(){
``var retryPolicy = _retryPolicyHelper.GetRetryPolicy<Some Return Type>();
}
```

Comment: What injection library are you using?

Comment: I'm using Autofac

Comment: Do you have code for where you register your components?  If this is all you have, you are missing that part.

Comment: I think an exception was thrown on the IRetryPolicyHelper implementation, please show your RetryPolicyHelper class

Comment: I was not registering them, that was the issue thanks so much.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: If you think this is not a duplicate, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE). Tip: a MRE is, at the very least, code that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Did you missed registration?

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<RetryPolicyHelper>().As<IRetryPolicyHelper>();
```